# Relay: Conditionally include fields in mutation's fat query

Tags: relayjs

While defining fragments of a Relay container, we can conditionally include or skip fields. [For example](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-ql.html#content), the following code includes `comments` only if `showComments` variable is `true`.

```
Relay.createContainer(Story, {
  initialVariables: {
    numCommentsToShow: 10,
    showComments: false,
  },
  fragments: {
    story: (variables) => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Story {
        comments(first: $numCommentsToShow) @include(if: $showComments) {
          edges {
            node {
              author { name },
              id,
              text,
            },
          },
        },
      }
    `,
  }
});
```

**How can we conditionally include fields in a [mutation's fat query](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-mutations.html#the-fat-query)?**

An use-use: Instead of having separate muttaions to update each field of a type, we could reuse the same mutation to update any field and *fetch only that field in response*. Doing so enables us to reduce payload.

This question is motivated by another question [Reusing a Mutation in Relay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37266178/reusing-a-mutation-in-relay).

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use string interpolation on the FatQuery:

```
getFatQuery() {
  return Relay.QL`
    fragment on EditCommentPayload {
      comment {
        ${this.props.fields.join(',')}
      }
    }
  `;
```

It seems a bit anti-GraphQL but unfortunately there are no variables for the fat query ([related issue](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1046)).

Comment: Interesting! However, it seems that it doesn't work always (ref: https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1046#issuecomment-241073226).